# Powershell Exchange Module remote mailbox issue

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, exchange-server, office365

I have created a scripts that automatically creates a user in Exchange and than adds a license to it from o365 however i need the box at the bottom where it says "automatically update email addresses based on the email address policy applied to this recipient" to automatically be checked off when the account is created.

[image]

Here is the main component that create the remote mail box:

```
New-RemoteMailBox -Alias $identAlias -Name $name -FirstName $return[0] -LastName $return[1] -UserPrincipalName $eAddress  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'xxxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried [get-mailbox](http://exchangeserverpro.com/manually-configuring-email-addresses-for-exchange-server-2013-recipients-using-powershell/) then change the property manually then get mailbox again and compare properties

Comment: No. I can't figure out which parameter controls that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply to [all users](http://doubledit.co.uk/2014/12/08/powershell-automatically-update-e-mail-address-based-on-recipient-policy/)

```
Get-mailbox | Set-mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true
```

and to restrict by domain

```
Get-mailbox | Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like ‘*@domain.com’} |
 Set-mailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $true
```

and remotely

```
Get-mailbox | Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like ‘*@domain.com’} |
Set-RemoteMailbox EmailAddressPolicyEnabled
```

Comment: Can this be used with set-remotemailbox instead of just set-mailbox?

Comment: Initial check, [yes it can](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607302%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). Existing mailbox will require [enable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607313%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: im sorry im a little confused what you mean by enable. could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: an example is in the link : Enable-RemoteMailbox "Kim Akers"